# Angular 2 mdDialog (one over second and after close all)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to do the next thing:
Firstly, I call one dialog, and if user click outside of it, pop up the one more dialog over the first one and ask user whether save or cancel. In anyway after user click save or cancel I want to close all dialogs, I know there is exist method "closeAll" in mdDialog,  but I can't understand how to make work it.
Here is plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/IZrpFYqCLvKSMLXjaW8g?p=preview

The issue is - when I click "save" or "cancel" - happens nothing.

Here is what I am trying to :
For the first dialog I set disableClose:

```
openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal },
      **disableClose:true**
    });
```

Then I use method backdropClick and if user click outside of dialog, I call the second dialog:

```
dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(backdrop => {
      if (backdrop == null) {
        **this.openDialogOver();**
    }
```

In the second dialog I put two buttons like this:

```
<div md-dialog-actions>
  <button md-button (click)="**onNoClick()**" >Save</button>
  <button md-button (click)="**onNoClick()**" >Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And set method onNoClick():

```
onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.**closeAll(**); // or **MdDialog.closeAll**  
  }
```

And that doesn't work :D

**UPD:**
I forget to add to second dialog to its constructor:

```
 constructor(public dialog: MdDialog)
```

And now it works well :)